# Type parameter list cannot be empty for TypeVarTuple

Tags: python, python-typing, type-variables

I have the following type parametrized signal:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing_extensions import Callable, TypeVarTuple, Generic, Unpack, List, TypeVar

VarArgs = TypeVarTuple('VarArgs')


class Signal(Generic[Unpack[VarArgs]]):

    def __init__(self):
        self.functions: List[Callable[..., None]] = []
        """
        Simple mechanism that allows abstracted invocation of callbacks. Multiple callbacks can be attached to a signal
        so that they are all called when the signal is emitted.
        """

    def connect(self, function: Callable[..., None]):
        """
        Add a callback to this Signal
        :param function: callback to call when emited
        """
        self.functions.append(function)

    def emit(self, *args: Unpack[VarArgs]):
        """
        Call all callbacks with the arguments passed
        :param args: arguments for the signal, must be the same type as type parameter
        """
        for function in self.functions:
            if args:
                function(*args)
            else:
                function()


def main():
    def signalEmptyCall():
        print("Hello!")

    signal: Signal[()] = Signal[()]()

    signal.connect(signalEmptyCall)

    signal.emit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem is that I cannot have empty argument list in the Callable:

```py
signal: Signal[()] = Signal[()]()
```

In Python 3.10 I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../main.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File ".../main.py", line 40, in main
    signal: Signal[()] = Signal[()]()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py", line 312, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/typing.py", line 1328, in __class_getitem__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Parameter list to Signal[...] cannot be empty
```

Reading the code in typing.py I find that Tuple is a special case (`if not params and cls is not Tuple:` where it doesn't crash for `Tuple[()]`), but TypeVarTuple has no special case, but is semantically a very similar thing.

Doing `signal: Signal = Signal()` works, but it seems like I am breaking something because PyCharm warns that `Expected type '(Any) -> None', got '() -> None' instead`.

How can I fix this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should probably be checking if the functions registered with the class accept the same arguments that `emit` does.

Comment: Yes they do, as I said, if I use Signal without type parameters it executes correctly.

Comment: No, my point is, you could declare something like `s = Signal[(int, int)]()`, but then call `s.connect(lambda x: None)`. In that case, `s.emit(3, 5)` will type check, but fail at runtime when you try to call `(lambda x: None)(3, 5)`.

Comment: But the code I have (`Signal` instead of `Signal[()]` for no param cases) doesn't fail at runtime, I don't think I made that kind of mistake, as PyCharm warns me correctly when the signal has parameters and is connected wrongly.

Comment: It *can*; I just gave you an example. Your type-checking only ensures that the `emit` method only takes arguments defined by the concrete `Signal` instance, not that you can only attach compatible functions to the instance.

Comment: The question here is how to hint that the Signal's function takes no arguments, could you provide an example of that that doesn't crash?, I will try to make a complete example to show you the error in godbolt now.

Comment: Testing some more, it seems the problem only happens with typing_extensions module in python3.10, not with typing in python3.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MikeWilliamson [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77820589/type-parameter-list-cannot-be-emtpy-for-typevartuple#comment137286513_77873557) this seems to be a problem in python3.10 because of an edge case of how types are implemented. And as @InSync [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77874127/3124150) `ParamSpec` should be used for `Callback` parameters.

The simplest solution here seems to be to have two Signals, one generic, and the other one to deal with this special case.

General case:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing_extensions import Callable, Generic, List, ParamSpec

VarArgs = ParamSpec('VarArgs')


class Signal(Generic[VarArgs]):
    """
    Simple mechanism that allows abstracted invocation of callbacks. Multiple callbacks can be attached to a signal
    so that they are all called when the signal is emitted.
    """

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.functions: List[Callable[VarArgs, None]] = []
        """
        Simple mechanism that allows abstracted invocation of callbacks. Multiple callbacks can be attached to a signal
        so that they are all called when the signal is emitted.
        """

    def connect(self, function: Callable[VarArgs, None]) -> None:
        """
        Add a callback to this Signal
        :param function: callback to call when emited
        """
        self.functions.append(function)

    def emit(self, *args: VarArgs.args, **kwargs: VarArgs.kwargs) -> None:
        """
        Call all callbacks with the arguments passed
        :param args: arguments for the signal, must be the same type as type parameter
        """
        for function in self.functions:
            function(*args, **kwargs)
```

Special case:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing_extensions import List, Callable


class SimpleSignal:
    """
    HACK for signals with no parameters. See Signal for a generic version.
    """

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.functions: List[Callable[[], None]] = []
        """
        Simple mechanism that allows abstracted invocation of callbacks. Multiple callbacks can be attached to a signal
        so that they are all called when the signal is emitted.
        """

    def connect(self, function: Callable[[], None]) -> None:
        """
        Add a callback to this SimpleSignal
        :param function: callback to call when emited
        """
        self.functions.append(function)

    def emit(self) -> None:
        """
        Call all callbacks
        """
        for function in self.functions:
            function()
```

Comment: This leads to worse results for PyCharm, by the way. I updated my answer to also include this.

Answer (score 0):

From [PEP 646 – Variadic Generics](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#args-as-a-type-variable-tuple):

> If no arguments are passed, the type variable tuple behaves like an empty tuple, Tuple[()]

So you can try this:

```py
appInitialization: Signal[()] = Signal()
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the problem seems to be in the type hint evaluation

Comment: Doing `appInitialization: Signal = Signal()` works, but it seems like I am breaking something because PyCharm warns that `Expected type '(Any) -> None', got '() -> None' instead `

Comment: Try removing [()] form the type hint?

Comment: Removing [()] makes PyCharm think that the function take `Any` as parameter and warns me

Comment: Okey , I m not sure about that

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take your code *exactly as is*, and it all worked fine... *if you use Python version 3.11*. I had the same problem as you when working with version 3.10, as you had.

So, my guess is that maybe you have some sort of conflict with versioning, so that how things *should work* isn't matching the documentation that you're reading on how they do work.

First, my result:

```py
>>> main()
Hello!
>>> signal: Signal[()] = Signal[()]()
>>> signal
<__main__.Signal object at 0x7f68c19439d0>
>>>
```

Next, my Python version:

```bash
> python --version
Python 3.11.7
```

AFAICT, you didn't do anything wrong, except there is maybe some underlying conflict.

Comment: OP is using Python 3.10 (see the traceback).

Comment: Thanks, @InSync .  I tried with `3.10`, and I did in fact get the exact same error as the OP.  IMHO, this seems like a corner case issue with how generic type hints were used when initially introduced in Python, and now it has been resolved.  My suggestion for the OP would be to either (a) bump the Python version, or (b) if that is not possible, don't try to work with the generic.  It's not helping to solve anything other than IDE type hinting, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson please update your answer indicating that the problem is replicable in version 3.10

Answer (score 0):

### Simplest solution

Add `from __future__ import annotations` to the top of your module. This will prevent Python from evaluating your type hints and therefore the code in `typing` that would otherwise raise the exception will never run.

Note that only it will only prevent type hints as variable annotations from being evaluated.

This will be fine:

```py
signal: Signal[()] = Signal()
```

...but this will not:

```py
signal = Signal[()]()
```

You can also remove all your type hints, but you probably don't want that.

Continue reading for better ways.

### Use `ParamSpec` instead

You don't actually want `TypeVarTuple`. You want `ParamSpec`. `TypeVarTuple` is used to pass an unknown number of *type parameters* to a generic. It is not usually used to specify the type of function parameters.

Also, AFAIK, a type checker won't be able to infer a type variable that is underterministic at the construction time depending on a later calls that might or might not happen. Not to mention, a `Signal` with no listeners is quite useless.

That said, if you can make the constructor accepting an initial listener, things will be much easier:

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=1010b882e385e1ace6719bef04903526), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?pythonVersion=3.10&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoDiApikSEgMYA0UACgIYj0QDKCRFAsAFCiRQUwAGyEcYSMCgDOAOnoAjCpmy58AYXoiFonj1pQAvHUbM2HABQByWpYCUu7hSH0pUqCyRoUm88VLkKAG1aAF1bAC4HKCghJCkYEjIpcJi4mECNLXlRYJoAOUkiEJCoqAATImAoAH1q1CQYWvMpIiFgGnrxTWrY%2BMSQFMznbKJcqALSMKgAWgA%2BccLI7mjolraZXoT-NyNAzqRuzf6S7h5oiqrBFFIKGGbW9tS%2B-0HNYZzafMKpuYXSJZWUDWwA2aX6snoCHYKDK5iO-nsp2W5UqUCIEAa9zaNAAVIw0Mk6HIQATcTiANYAd3xhNoMipNNsM3mEyIAJWwFwTy2ZEwKCBD1BzyS7MB8LI5jxJKkZIZ0sRPAuQPocGqAAskOYmb9WeyEOQUHdLAAJVpCMAAQjsDiVUhV6qQ1RgYHMMHxRBgKXiIG1LMWZyg%2BtQd2AJrNYCgAG83SSPQBfK0K7hSTzeISGdypnx21UapMpryaGRXG53HMOp1gREAYigEEQcEBBnmZHAAygAEESQBXCAkfAARlgEYARCWxCOoGAqiOPIWhJO1S4%2BYJsPRxCNYIgiFAR0NtKNAt6Ql9JiOANxogAe7FuRDKu-3I0CgRPfyKI54tdocHIaDV%2BDNmiIBtikXZoL2-ZTlU8DsLurrup6QIwD6zLvpOFD0NcYD4PIO4uAWpAPs6gYmH2CQgLu4ogJO05bnBI5amhrKTqgUDAN2KC3BI-JjpIpaftw35wGoS4gNAzYOIRRbopiNadiIKTAKgRBSVmQgyLJRqUrgQhlNaQl1g2TYtiBuApAAKmAEYQFhjb4pBhpuJylEjlptEznOaaCcJf4AYY8wAKI3mI95QAADIGYApuIkiaFADl9k5X50CJYkSfMACqpAhXeD6JVB5h8NADBMKwt5QNYBlAA))</sub>

```py
class Signal(Generic[P]):

  listeners: list[Callable[P, None]]

  def __init__(self, initial_listener: Callable[P, None]) -> None:
    self.listeners = [initial_listener]

  def connect(self, listener: Callable[P, None]) -> None:
    self.listeners.append(listener)

  def emit(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> None:
    for listener in self.listeners:
      listener(*args, **kwargs)
```

For the following setup code:

```py
def say_hi() -> None:
  print('Hello!')

def say_hi_to(target: str) -> None:
  print(f'Hello {target}!')

signal = Signal(say_hi)
```

...we get these results:

```py
signal.connect(say_hi_to)
# mypy    => error: Argument 1 to "connect" of "Signal" has incompatible type "Callable[[str], None]"; expected "Callable[[], None]"
# Pyright => error: Argument of type "(target: str) -> None" cannot be assigned to parameter "listener" of type "() -> None" in function "connect" 
# PyCharm => fine (incorrect)

signal.emit()
# All: fine

signal.emit('world')
# mypy    => error: Too many arguments for "emit" of "Signal"
# Pyright => Expected 0 positional arguments
# PyCharm => Unexpected argument (from ParamSpec 'P')
```

You *can also* use `ParamSpec` *without* specifying an initial listener, but the results won't be as good.

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=1383162bd5d7fb1b63f79dee62946c6e), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?pythonVersion=3.10&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoDiApikSEgMYA0UACgIYj0QDKCRFAsAFCiRQUwAGyEcYSMCgDOAOnoAjCpmy58AYXoiFonj1pQAvHUbM2HABQByWpYCUu7hSH0pUqCyRoUm88VLkKAG1aAF1bAC4HKCghJCkYEjIpcJi4mECNLXlRYJoAOUkiEJCoqAATImAoAH1q1CQYWvMpIiFgWygAWgA%2BKALSSO5o6Ja2mVj4xJA3I0CS7h5oiqrBFFIKGGbW4BoJhP8UzOdsoly%2BwrCu3v6iQeGoUeBxtKnZegR2FDLzPan7BaG5UqUCIEAaWzaNAAVIw0Mk6HIQHDoVCANYAd1h8NoMgxWI6PXOA0Ww2AuFSk38mBQD22z0pSTu9wp%2BzI5hhSKkKLxnP%2BPGWD3ocGqAAskOYCddCkyEOQUJtLAAJVpCMAAQjsDgFUiFoqQ1RgYHMMFhRBgKXiIElRNuJNlqE2wCVKrAUAA3iakWaAL4avncKSebxCFIeLyaQJzEKGdxBnz%2BwPhoQyVbrTY64Vi-4AYigAEERClgKgiA5E8GU5I081dWKDWAc1AIIg4FAAGR0ODkNAi-AGXo6iBEEEgcAgHi52hwNQixjQZnRftQYukKDmVCCUdiBNx5Og8GNgsh5clsu7mT7hXo3BCMqa7i55sIVsdqfd3uGAfMYdkMcTzsznOC6Lr0K7DuuKCbiA25AA))</sub>

```py
...
class Signal(Generic[P]):
  ...
  def __init__(self) -> None:
    self.listeners = []
  ...
```

```py
signal: Signal[[]] = Signal()  # Fine both at type checking time and at runtime
```

Now PyCharm just passes everything:

```py
signal.connect(say_hi)
# All: fine

signal.connect(say_hi_to)
# mypy & Pyright => same error
# PyCharm        => fine (incorrect)

signal.emit()
# All: fine

signal.emit('world')
# mypy & Pyright => same error
# PyCharm        => fine (incorrect)
```

### Still want to use `TypeVarTuple`?

The first `ParamSpec` solution works best for PyCharm, since it has somewhat decent support for `ParamSpec`. For `TypeVarTuple`, not so much.

If you insists on using the latter, you need to specify the type of a listener to be `Callable[[` `Unpack[Ts]` `], None]`. It doesn't matter to PyCharm either way, but people using other type checkers would prefer you do that.

<sub>(playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=da4db15f3d77cef1a18161e818a28561), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?pythonVersion=3.10&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmUkQWEMoDiApikSEgMYCwAUKJLIqmgPpEAeMJAzkmCt0zZc%2BAKooEAQwoBrADRQAKoiIA1SSEUBXBABsitetAphd%2BijD4CAdJIBGFITjxQAwpLP39tWosEBeJRV1TR19AAoAcj9IgEofGgpdSW5BAGUkNBQPcOJScgoAbXEpWUK-AF0K2IAuBKgoXSRuLnzuGsbmmEL3Tzt9QuKJaRly7iqFADl%2BIir6qAATImAoFhZUJBg18O4iXWAFDcsPFiaWkjIO3uT%2BokGSkbGJqGnSaqgAWgA%2BF5m6mgaDV2%2B2sZ1aZACUEKRyQJzBFxAFXmSxWJhQpAsOz2B0653yVw8NwGQ1Ko0qFSmM3e31%2BpH%2BgKgwOAoK6CO4tgQCBIC3C8Py8RotAaKKgRAgmyx%2BwUACoNGh2lAHmVKrFPj9XkR6YDgLhceCQJgUIzsSy8RCtQy%2BWRwrKQPKBbQRdxJHAWAALJDhVU0jVahDkFAwKIACT2ujAAEI4gknS73UgWDAwOEYHKiDAOi0QN71X8hVB-agg5FQ2YwFAAN6pu3pgC%2BUYdNF4WQ8HQyLd0hS9FSggXb2V0OzjHoFLF7jMyA9N%2Bu4hQADEim5OPNY0Rig87XR7E2ABQBiKAQRBwBn%2BH5kcAgDoAQTtWggJHwAEZYOWAERrogWN9QMArN-9h4P5uikhomNgkiWLcjBclAb7XF4dyFFmFK0rMb4ANyiuwXIWEQCxwQhtyDKhGoVG%2BtAHgACnA5BoG6%2BBnqKICXjed4PoGv4rPAsFvimaYZoyMDZmqaE-hQkjomA%2BB2EQUApM2pAEUmBYaJID5cAab5WiAP5-jBcl8TmYmGlAwBaCgFhWHBn7fgkikrmKEr7lA15mB0wCoAYgpLh21hOcWADuuC6As0Y0AeR4ICegJMReuAdIoYDlhAkknnK96PoIOpaQFen-oBugURFUA0XRDG9j8ACiOFflwBFzgWYC8JY-AePJ7FZbQQA))</sub>

```py
Ts = TypeVarTuple('Ts')

class Signal(Generic[Unpack[Ts]]):

  listeners: list[Callable[[Unpack[Ts]], None]]

  def __init__(self, initial_listener: Callable[[Unpack[Ts]], None]) -> None:
    self.listeners = [initial_listener]

  def connect(self, listener: Callable[[Unpack[Ts]], None]) -> None:
    self.listeners.append(listener)

  def emit(self, *args: Unpack[Ts]) -> None:
    for listener in self.listeners:
      listener(*args)
```

The errors are the same for mypy and Pyright, but for PyCharm, it fails miserably.
You can make it quiet with `# noqa` or `# type: ignore` if you want to.

```py
signal = Signal(say_hi)    # warning: Expected type '(Any) -> None', got '() -> None' instead (incorrect)
```

```py
signal.connect(say_hi_to)  # fine (incorrect)
signal.emit()              # fine (correct)
signal.emit('world')       # fine (incorrect)
```

Comment: "Also, AFAIK, a type checker won't be able to infer a type variable that is underterministic at the construction time depending on a later calls that might or might not happen." That is why I want to _explicitly_ tell Python the types (constructing with the syntax Signal[X, Y]). The problem is with the case where the signal takes no parameters, Signal[()]() doesn't have "undefined parameters", it explicitly has 0 parameters.

Comment: I will try to implement your ParamSpec solution, and provide feedback, thanks

Comment: I have tested a few things: `from __future__ import annotations` doesn't work, in fact I have it in the question and fails. Your constructor-with-callback hack is more convoluted than just implementing a dedicated "signal with no parameters", and having to pass a "real" (non dummy) signal as parameter breaks the modularity of the event manager. As for using TypeVarTuple, I understant that I should now use ParamSpec. Awarding bounty as this answer was helpful.

Comment: @EmmanuelMess It should be noted that `from __future__ import annotations` only allow `signal: Signal[()] = Signal()`, not `signal = Signal[()]()`; either of them would be suffice as a type hint otherwise.